# Swift: Trying to create a generic type initializer

Tags: ios, swift, generics, types, initialization

I'm **banging** my head over here

. 
I'm trying to solve this "easy" to understand issue.
I have an `API Endpoint` which i'm sending to request from many different classes. Let's assume I have a `Tweet` class and `User` class.

```
class Tweet {

    var id: String!
    var description: String!

    required init() { }

 }

class User {

    var id: String!
    var username: String!
    var likes : Int!

    required init() { }

 }
```

Now, Depending on the `Class` request origin, I'll get a respond with an `Array` that each element holds the exact same properties as the source `Class` as `JSON`. Sample request from `Tweet` `Class`:

```
  "data":
  [{
     {
     "id": "492",
     "description": "HELP!"
     },
     {
     "id": "574",
     "description": "ME!"
     }
   ]}
```

Now, I'm trying to create a `Generic Method` which automatically parse those into an `Array` with objects from the passes `Class` type.
**This is what i've tried**

```
func sendRequest<T>(resource: T.Type,withProperyList propList : [String], completion: @escaping ([T]?) -> ()) { 


// Create NSURLSession request, fetching data.. converting to json..

guard let mainArray = json["data"] as? NSArray else { return }

for element in mainArray  {

      let tweet = T() // **Error here**

 }
```

**Error: ** 'T' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers**

**How can I access my `Generic Type Class` in a generic way? Meaning that i'll pass the `Class` type and be able to apply it to 'T'. I've tried passing it theu the input parameters but it won't help. I just can't figure it out. Any ideas?**

Comment: Wait for Swift 4 and its built-in JSON en-/decoder. Since your classes contain different properties it's not possible with generics anyway.

Comment: Hey @vadian. Thank you for responding. Do you happend to know when is the official release date?

Comment: No, but usually in September or October

Comment: @vadian Cool. Hey vadian, I know it's not appropriated, but i wondered if there any chance we can open a quick chat for a question i've got in Swift. It's about storing and retrieving arrays with big amount of objects. Totally understand if you'll refuse :)

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: @vadian Sorry for my ignorance, did you mean by opening a thread or by asking here at the comments section?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148718/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-vadian).

Comment: I mean [please ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: hey @vadian , posted :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995028/swift-performance-wise-comparing-two-arrays-and-get-the-difference-in-each-a . Hope you'll be able to assist me!  Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `T()`, give this a shot.

```
let tweet = resource.init()
```